# s3fs/botocore import error: InvalidIMDSEndpointError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, botocore, python-s3fs

I was trying to run some python code in docker and export a .csv file to S3, but got the same error as in [aiobotocore - ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidIMDSEndpointError'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65688584/) (asking here because I don't have enough reputation to comment under that thread..)

```
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import S3FileSystem, S3File
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 14, in <module>
    import aiobotocore
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiobotocore/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .session import get_session, AioSession
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiobotocore/session.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import AioClientCreator, AioBaseClient
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiobotocore/client.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils import AioS3RegionRedirector
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiobotocore/utils.py", line 10, in <module>
    from botocore.exceptions import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidIMDSEndpointError' from 'botocore.exceptions' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/exceptions.py)
```

I tried to use the versions of libraries as in the comment:
`botocore==1.19.52`
`s3fs==0.5.1`
`boto3==1.16.52`
`aiobotocore==1.2.0`
However, these don't solve the problem and I still get the same error.

Could anyone here give me some hints how to solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can answer my own question :)
Just install s3fs, and it will take care of version dependencies of other libraries..