# Python3: ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidProxiesConfigError' from 'botocore.httpsession'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, botocore, python-s3fs

My use case is that I am trying to write my dataframe to S3 bucket for which I installed `s3fs==2015.5.0` using pip3. Now when I run the code

```
import s3fs

def my_func():
    # my logic


my_func()
```

It returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import s3fs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/s3fs/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import S3FileSystem, S3File
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 14, in <module>
    import aiobotocore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/aiobotocore/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .session import get_session, AioSession
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/aiobotocore/session.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import AioClientCreator, AioBaseClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/aiobotocore/client.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .args import AioClientArgsCreator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/aiobotocore/args.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .endpoint import AioEndpointCreator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/aiobotocore/endpoint.py", line 12, in <module>
    from aiobotocore.httpsession import AIOHTTPSession
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/aiobotocore/httpsession.py", line 12, in <module>
    from botocore.httpsession import ProxyConfiguration, create_urllib3_context, \
ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidProxiesConfigError' from 'botocore.httpsession' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/botocore/httpsession.py)
```

My requirements.txt file something like this:

```
boto3==1.18.65
s3fs==2021.5.0
fastparquet==0.7.1
```

`pip3 install -r requirements.txt` install the packages but also returns

```
 aiobotocore 1.4.2 requires botocore<1.20.107,>=1.20.106, but you'll have botocore 1.19.28 which is incompatible.
s3fs 2021.5.0 requires fsspec==2021.05.0, but you'll have fsspec 2021.10.1 which is incompatible.
```

For some reason it just started to happen now. I was using the similar packages earlier and it was working fine. Any ideas why it is not working now?

Comment: Seems your modules now require conflicting versions. On a side note, S3 is not a filesystem, it's a flat object store and attempts at making it more FS-like are usually not great.

Comment: @jordanm I was actually not trying to use s3fs at all. But somehow when I try to write pandas df to S3 it returns the error that you need to install s3fs.

Comment: You should take a look on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65688584/aiobotocore-importerror-cannot-import-name-invalidimdsendpointerror